# atan() returns Nan

Tags: javascript

I am writing my first project in JavaScript. As I understand, Math.atan() returns a number (angle in radians). 
But somehow, it returns Nan.

Using console.log(), I have checked all the variables (ry, rx, this.y, this.x), and all are numbers. But for

```
console.log(Bullet.q)
```

i get "NaN".

```
function createBullet(rx, ry){
    let Bullet = kontra.Sprite({
        x: player.x,
        y: player.y,
        v: 4,
        q: Math.atan((ry-this.y)/(rx-this.x)),
       // k: this.v/Math.sqrt((ry-this.y)*(ry-this.y)+(rx-this.x)*(rx-this.x)),
        //dx: (rx-this.x)*this.k,
        dx: Math.cos(this.q)*this.v,
        //dy: (ry-this.y)*this.k,
        dy: Math.sin(this.q)*this.v,

    });

    console.log(ry);
    console.log(Bullet.q);
    console.log(Bullet.dy);

}
```

I am new to this language, am I missing something?

Comment: you need to use a getter to reach sibling own properties using `this.property`, otherwise, `this` is lexical to the surrounding scope. in other words, `this.x` is not `Bullet.x`.

Comment: Is there a possibility of `rx-this.x` being `0` ?

Comment: you need to return Bullet from the function, call it to retrieve the value.

Comment: actually the simple fix is to just change `this.x` to `player.x`, since that's what you need and it's right there anyway. same for `y`...

Comment: @DominikMatis no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a "clever" way to do it by taking advantage of JS's leaky assignments and using an extra top-level var to store the property you need outside the object literal:

```
function createBullet(rx, ry){
    var q,v;
    let Bullet = kontra.Sprite({
        x: player.x,
        y: player.y,
        v: v = 4,
        q: q= Math.atan((ry-player.y)/(rx-player.x)),
        dx: Math.cos(q)*v,
        dy: Math.sin(q)*v,

    });

    console.log(ry);
    console.log(Bullet.q);
    console.log(Bullet.dy);

}
```

that said, i don't really like clever code and you might want to compute those properties before the literal, for better readability.

The way a getter could be used inline:

```
var obj = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 get sum() { return this.a+this.b}
};

alert(obj.sum);
```